# Best choice for sending large amount of records in Java WebSerivce (REST vs WebSocket)

Tags: java, android, rest, websocket, large-data

I am developing an application for Android, for use in agricultural machine.

This application will generate on average 10 to 40 logs per minute.

After 20 hours, there will be from 12,000 to 48,000 records stored in SQLite.

**My question is about the best choice to submit these records to the server using the Internet.**

Today I am using a Java Web application with JSF pages and JAX-RS (Jersey) for communication with Android. For the database I am using PostgreSQL 9 connecting via JPA (EclipseLink).

In tests I'm doing, it seems to me to be problematic send all this data via REST, because the process is lengthy. I'm having timeout problems
and among other things.

To try to work around the problem and ensure data consistency. I am sending the data in paging, and start the database insertion only after sending all records.

This solves part of the problem, but I'm not sure that will be the best approach. The insertion of data on the server is lengthier and Android can not wait for the process to complete, due to timeout.

Thus, the user is not sure that the process was successful. Only after a long time, the insertion end and the user can confirm that the process was successful.

It also generates other problems, because I have to prevent the user to perform a new sending data until it receives confirmation from the previous process.

**What is the best solution for this type of case?**

One of the solutions that I intend to look is WebSocket, but would like to know the experience of other developers.

Comment: Is your server stateful? If so why don't you make the requests asynchronous so as soon as the POST is finished, the client request returns which will then allow you to do some polling on the state of the processing? This gets around the issue of timeouts and allows a level of user feedback; it doesn't sound as if the problem is the communication mechanism.

Comment: I think about it. Today I do something like that. But I do a manual control of the process, I keep an ID/STATUS in the session.But all this seems insecure. Processes can crash and I lose control over them. Is there any elegant solution to run these processes?

Comment: It looks like your set up is not using available tools like ajax, and I would be very concerned if I couldn't keep a handle on existing running processes or excessive timeouts.  You need to fix those first!  However, this may prove useful http://blog.arungupta.me/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What I understand is that websocket will only change the way you connect to server. Because I still have to manually control the long processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and evaluation, I get a good solution for this case. The process of upload and store the records to the server was under 40 seconds.

In the Android application I'm using the following set:

- **[Realm database](https://github.com/realm/realm-java) to store the data**: Its advantage is not load all data into memory when running a query. The data is loaded on demand.
- **[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) to serialize to Json**: Its advantage is to serialize the data and write to file on demand. I had to create a custom serializer.
- **`GZIPOutputStream` to compress the data**: Allows Jackson writes compressed data.
- **[Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to upload the data**: Because is beautiful :)

The result of this set was very good for me. It is possible to read, compress and send 50,000 records of Android to the server in about 15 seconds. The compressed data is approximately 400KB.

In the server:

- **[JPA & EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) + [PostgresSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) to store the data**: With some extra settings you can get a great performance.
- **[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) to deserialize the Json**: I had to create a custom deserializer.
- **`GZIPInputStream` to uncompress the data**: Allows Jackson read the compressed data.
- **[Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) to receive requests**: Is a very good implementation to work with CDI + EJB.

The server receives the compressed data and store to disk. After a task is scheduled to uncompress and insert in the database. The process takes 15 to 20 seconds to 50,000 records.

That was good for me, I hope this can contribute to other developers as well.